# Quote Delimiter Function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, function, delimiter, quote

I want to quote delimit the variables in my dynamic sql using a function. Oracle 11gR2.

I.E. Is there a function in built-in oracle that accomplishes this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_QuoteDelimiter (
 iString      IN VARCHAR2,
 iDelimiter   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '[]')
 RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
 oString   VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
 oString :=
     'q'''
  || SUBSTR (iDelimiter, 1, 1)
  || iString
  || SUBSTR (iDelimiter, 2, 1)
  || '''';
RETURN oString;
END;
/
```

Comment: No such built-in finction.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?  If you're using dynamic SQL, surely you're using bind variables, right?  You're not dynamically creating SQL statements with embedded string literals, are you?  That would be an excellent way to crush your database.